# Git lab showing "There are no commits yet" after my git reset?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, git-checkout, git-revert

I have three branches in my GitLab

1. Main
2. ppp7
3. ppp7-master

> ppp7---> ppp7-master---> main

every day I'm pushing my new code into ppp7 branch.if code is running fine in ppp7 branch, i create new merge request to ppp7-master branch.until here all three branches are have same code only. whats happen yesterday i pushed a wrong code into ppp7 branch.after i merge that ppp7 code into other two branches.but that code failing on all environment. so here i reset ppp7 branch code to previous commit using below comments.

```
$ git reset --hard 725bb8011bbb2535053feffd441f01d3059fea56
HEAD is now at 725bb80 Update emp.sql
$ git add .
```

```
$ git commit -m "where condition removed"
On branch ppp7
Your branch is behind 'origin/ppp7' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git push -f origin ppp7
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for ppp7, visit:
```

```
 + 2cb0310...725bb80 ppp7 -> ppp7 (forced update)
```

now my ppp7 branch have working code, other two branches have wrong code. so i'm creating new merge request to ppp7-master. but I'm cant merge gitlab showing "There are no commits yet."
[There are no commits yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/add0r.png)
why I'm cant merge both branches have different code.also when i compare both branches its showing  "Showing with 0 additions and 0 deletions". how its possible both branches have different code.

1. [when comparing ppp7 branch with
   ppp7-master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRqT3.png)
2. [when i comparing ppp7-master with
   ppp7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gArs1.png)

I'm needed to merge new reset code into ppp7-master and why this error showing.

Comment: You talk about GitLab, but you have [tag:github] as one of your tags. Note that while GitLab "MRs" and GitHub "PRs" share a lot of characteristics (because they have the same goals, more or less), they are different and what applies on one does not necessarily apply on the other. Pick the one you're actually using, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below one working for me.

```
git checkout 725bb8 .
git commit -m "rollback to 725bb8 "
git push origin ppp7
```

now my working code with new commit.Now i able to create a merge request with ppp7-master.

### when i use this comment

1. no need to use force push
2. no need for reset and revert comment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Pull/Merge Request functionality to update a branch with a reset. Pull/Merge Requests can only *add* new commits to a branch; you can't *remove* commits. Instead you have two options:

1. Force push all of the branches that need to be reset.
2. Use `git revert` instead of `git reset`. In Git, "revert" will create a new commit that effectively undoes the changes of a specific commit (or multiple commits if undoing a merge commit).

Answer (score 0):

Note: the right command nowadays would be [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

As its name suggests, `git restore`... *restores* files (in the working tree and/or the index), and opposed to [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), which switches branches. (While the old `git checkout` can do both and is therefore confusing)

In your case:

```
git switch ppp7
git restore --source=725bb8 --staged --worktree -- .
```

Or, abbreviated form:

```
git restore -s 725bb8 -SW
```

Then you can commit, push, and make your pull requests.